# get variable with string without if-else in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to obtain the value of a variable using a string to minimize the use of large if-else statements. For example:

```
string a = "hello world";
string b = "foo";

string input;

cout << "a or b";
cin >> input;

//is something like the next line possible?
cout << "your answer is equal to " << string_to_variable(input) << endl;
```

this should output "hello world" if the user inputted "a", and "foo" if the user inputted "b".

Thanks.

Comment: If you need lots of these (e.g., as part of a text adventure game), you can still use a declarative approach via something like a map.

Comment: One solution would be to store the values in a map with the key being what you want the user input to be and the do the map lookup on the output.

Comment: Another solution is to use case statements. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch this link provides examples on how to use them in case you don't already know. This alleviates the need for an external data structure.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to obtain the value of a variable using a string to minimize the use of large if-else statements.

You can use `std:map<std::string, std::string>` to make programming easier but underneath that, it still uses a lot of compares and `if-else` type checks.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>> mymap = {{"a", "hello world"}, {"b", "foo"}};

std::string input;

cout << "a or b";
cin >> input;

//is something like the next line possible?
cout << "your answer is equal to " << maymap[input] << endl;
```

If you want your code to be more precise, you can use:

```
auto it = mymap.find(input);
if ( it == mymap.end() )
{
   cout << "There is no answer corresponding to " << input << endl;
}
else
{
   cout << "your answer is equal to " << it->second << endl;
}
```

instead of

```
cout << "your answer is equal to " << maymap[input] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

a and b are variable names that only exist in your source code and are not available for you at runtime. To accomplish something like what you are looking for try creating a map from input string to output string.

```
map<string, string> inputMapping;
inputMapping["a"] = "hello world";
inputMapping["b"] = "foo";

string input;

cout << "a or b";
cin >> input;

result = inputMapping[input];
cout << "your answer is equal to " << result << endl;
```

Note that you ideally want to do some input sanitation and perhaps use inputMapping.find rather than the [] operator to identify when you get unknown input too. With this setup you can support whatever amount of input strings to match and add them dynamically throughout your program. You can learn more about maps here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map